# C++: Initializing a reference member to an object created in the initialization list

Tags: c++, reference, initialization, initializer-list

Consider the following code:

```
class Foo {
    Foo() {}
};

class Bar {
    Foo &Foo_ref;
    Bar() : Foo_ref() {}
};
```

Complied as is, I get the error:

```
tmp.cc: In constructor Bar::Bar():
tmp.cc:7: error: value-initialization of Foo& Bar::Foo_ref, which has reference type
```

I've tried every variation I can think of. What am I doing wrong? How do I initialize a reference member to a new instance?
I'm using a const pointer instead of a reference as a workaround for now, but I'd prefer to use a reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's wrong with

```
class Bar
{
    Foo myFoo;
    Bar() : myFoo() {}
};
```

if you want a brand-new Foo object?

Comment: I... hrm.  
I could have sworn I had a good reason not to do that at one point, but I can't think of it now. The only thing I can see is that, with a reference, I can import Foo.h in Bar.cc instead of Bar.h - I prefer to import in the body instead of the header wherever possible.  
At the very least, it's a better workaround that a const pointer. Thanks!

Comment: Can you help please.  I am trying to understand how this works.  I would like a class with a protected member `Foo myFoo` and 2 constructors `Bar()` and `Bar(Foo initFoo)`.  The first constructor should create a new instance for myFoo.  I thought that because of the second constructor that the member variable should be a reference (and maybe my second constructor should use a reference parameter too) - but then I am a little confused.

Comment: @Ben: I'm confused by your description.  Is the `Bar` object supposed to be linked to the `Foo` passed in to the one-argument constructor, such that it sees future changes to that `Foo` instance?  If so, you'll need a reference parameter in the constructor, and a reference member variable.  For the zero-argument case where you want a new `Foo` instance, you need a non-reference member variable, which the reference can bind to.  Luchian's answer shows this in code.

Comment: @BenVoigt thanks for your help, I think I figured this out.  I am coming from a C# background where class members start as references (and need to be initialized).  In C++ class members are automatically instantiated and I think this is what confused me. I have also been reading about the automatic copy constructor.

Answer (score 7):

A reference must always be binded to an object. You have to pass an object you want to have reference to in your constructor

```
Bar(Foo &foo) : Foo_ref(foo)
{
}
```

If you don't want (or can't) pass `Foo` into `Bar` constructor - you have to use pointer:

```
class Bar {
    Foo *Foo_ptr;
    Bar() : Foo_ptr(nullptr) {}
};
```

You can think about the reference member variable as a pointer which must be binded in initializer list

Comment: Not necessarily. See my answer.

Comment: @Luchian: Your answer missed a case also (can bind to a member variable).

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I want to create the object on the spot. My workaround is `Foo_constpointer(new Foo())` - is there no way to do this with pointers?

Comment: @BenVoigt good point, provided it's initialized before the reference.

Comment: @Luchian: I don't think that actually matters, as long as you don't use the reference before its target gets initialized (seeing as how a reference is bound to a memory location, not an object).  But I definitely do prefer the order you described.

Comment: @BenVoigt really? Isn't it UB?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: It's 3.8p6 that allows it.

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor has to either take a parameter, set the reference to a member that is initialized before the reference or set the reference to a global `Foo` object. You can't bind the reference to a temporary (which, even if the reference is `const`, would only live until the constructor ends.

```
extern Foo gFoo;

class Bar {
    Foo foo;
    Foo &Foo_ref;
    Bar() : Foo_ref(gFoo) {}
    //or
    //Bar() : Foo_ref(foo) {}
    Bar(Foo& foo) : Foo_ref(foo) {}
};
```

Comment: The member order doesn't actually matter -- binding references is one of the few things that's expressly permitted to do with a location that will hold an object in the future but doesn't yet.